# Using adaptive popover segue and wrapping the destination in a navigation controller leads to memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, popover, uistoryboardsegue

Let's say I have a view controller that I show using an *adaptive popover segue* when clicking on a button. Now in some cases, I might want to wrap the destination view controller in (for example) a navigation controller. So, I set myself as the delegate for the `popoverPresentationController`'s delegate, and implement the `presentationController:viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:` method.

---

But I noticed something strange: in some cases, objects were not being deallocated. If, in the previously mentioned method, I wrap the presented viewcontroller in a navigation controller:

```
func presentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
    return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
}
```

On dismiss the navigation controller gets deallocated, but the presented view controller remains allocated.

If, in contrast, I directly show a navigation controller via adaptive popover segue, then on dismiss both the navigation controller and the details controller it contains get deallocated correctly.

---

For demonstration purposes, please refer to this test project (Swift): https://github.com/djbe/AdaptivePopoverSegue-Test

What we get when dynamically wrapping in a navigation controller (tap the "Popover, nav automatically added" button):

```
--- Showing details ---
Loaded details view controller (0x7fab31632b70)
Loaded navigation controller (0x7fab32815600)
Deinit navigation controller (0x7fab32815600)
```

As you can see, the details view controller is never deallocated.

---

I checked the documentation for `presentationController:viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:` but there are no specific mentions of ownership, strong retains, etc...
I tried using Instruments with the Allocations tool, but there are so many retain/releases involved in this (simple) case that I couldn't directly find the problem.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Or do you have an idea on how to solve this?

---

## Solution

As mentioned below by @TomSwift, there is a bug due to a circular reference between the controller and the segue. The only way to solve this, and still wrap the destination controller in a navigation controller, is by doing the *wrapping* in the init method of the segue (custom).

I've updated my sample code on Github to showcase how this would be achieved using the solution as mentioned by @Vasily, but still allow for dynamic wrapping behaviour using protocols, without resorting to hacky workarounds using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I've added some extra init logs, so you can see which objects are allocated + also log the addresses for extra verification.

Comment: See if it reproduces on iOS 10. If so, make sure to open a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I see that it reproduces in the iOS 10 simulator.   Xcode 8 debugger shows two circular references holding the controller in memory; both are internal to UIKit.  I'd file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @djbe It's nice to see a solution you posted, but you didn't use `presentationController:viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:` at all though. Your solution wouldn't apply if one wants the presented controller to adaptively add the navigation controller wrapper through that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

You need to create custom UIStoryboardSegue class and override init function.

Sample:

```
class StoryboardSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override init(identifier: String?, source: UIViewController, destination: UIViewController) {
    super.init(identifier: identifier, source: source, destination: NavigationController(rootViewController: destination))
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

[image]

**result**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this isn't a solution. In fact it uses more memory than my current code.

Here's the log output from your solution:
`--- Showing details ---
Loaded details view controller (0x7fe75352eef0)
Loaded navigation controller (0x7fe75482e800)
Loaded details view controller (0x7fe7536222c0)
Deinit navigation controller (0x7fe75482e800)
Deinit details view controller (0x7fe7536222c0)`

As you can see, 2 details view controllers get allocated, but only 1 is deallocated.

Comment: Also, your solution didn't work correctly until I added a correct reuse and restoration identifiers to the details scene.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Decision not yet exist but I left some more thoughts on this issue.

Comment: Interesting! I'll take a look at your suggestion, test it thoroughly and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: wrap segues destinationViewController from ViewController code added. I hope, this is a solution)

Comment: Have you found a solution of your question?

Comment: I've adapted your solution into something that's a little less hacky (imo) and pushed the changes to github so everyone take a look at it.

Comment: The essential part from your solution is correct, the navigation controller should replace the destination controller during init. The mechanism itself is up to the developer.

Comment: If you clean up your solution, I'll accept it. Essentially just the code for the segue with the init override. Oh and maybe attribute @TomSwift, he found the actual memory leak.

Comment: It is good that a solution was found. The answer has been edited.

Comment: Thx. You should remove the "Idea 1" part, as it's wrong and uses more (double?) the memory.

Answer (score 4):

Using XCode8 I noted that there is a circular reference between the `DetailsViewController` and the `UIStoryboardSegue`.  I don't see a way to cleanly break this cycle as it's internal to UIKit.  There's seemingly a secondary circular reference involving an `NSDictionary` ivar "_externalObjectsTableForLoading".  You should report this to Apple!

[image]

A solution is to not reuse the `DetailsViewController` that was pre-loaded by the segue.  If you manually instantiate it yourself you can bypass this problem.  Here's a possible implementation (requires you set the restoration identifier in the storyboard!):

```
func presentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
    if (wrapInNavigationController) {
        let vc = controller.presentedViewController
        if let restorationIdentifier = vc.restorationIdentifier {
            return NavigationController(rootViewController: vc.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(restorationIdentifier))
        }
    }
    return controller.presentedViewController
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know Xcode 8 provided this! From a quick search, is it the new "memory graph" feature?

Comment: Your suggested solution was mentioned first by @vasily, and unfortunately, it's not really a solution as the presented controller is allocated twice, and deallocated only once. So the memory leak remains.